# If I change permissions on a tar file, will that apply to the files inside it?

Tags: permissions, tar, chmod, chown

I have a script that runs regularly via `cron`, that creates a `tar.gz` file for the purpose of backing up a directory.

For reasons beyond my control, the only user who can execute the script via `cron` is a root user. So the resulting `tar` file can not be moved or deleted by any other user.

So, as part of the script, I want to execute a `chown` and `chmod` on the `tar` file so that other users can manipulate it.

But is it good enough to just change permissions on the `tar` file, or will the root user permissions also be saved to the files inside the `tar`? When a user unpacks the `tar` file, will they be able to act on those files as if they created the files themselves?

Comment: "So the resulting tar file can not be moved or deleted by any other user." — not true. Un-linking is possible when a user has Write permission set for directory (unless it has setuid bit set as well like `/tmp` for e. g.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the user extracting is a "ordinary" user, the files will be owned by that user (by default).

From the manual page of tar

```
--same-owner
       try extracting files with the same ownership as exists in the archive (default for superuser)

--no-same-owner
       extract files as yourself (default for ordinary users)
```

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: **No.**

The `tar` utility is made specially for archiving directory structures under unix-like systems. It preserves all the ownership and permission information of the files/directories included¹. Regardless of the user running the `tar` command.

At least this is case of standard invocation. But I presume that if you were to exercise any advanced `tar` options that might change permission handling, you wouldn't have asked this question :)

¹  <sub>One exception: regular `tar` does not preserve SELinux settings or acls.  You need `star` or a recent version of `tar` to preserve those.
See also http://magazine.redhat.com/2007/07/02/tips-from-an-rhce-tar-vs-star-the-battle-of-xattrs/.
You may need to take that into consideration if the files backed up have any extended attributes.</sub>